# Save user selection after search in views

Tags: 7, views

I am facing a problem with views. Is it possible somehow to save the user selection when a user is doing a search?

To get it clearer, I'm having a list of users. Let's say, I am searching for customer A via filters, then select the found customer, change my filter to find customer B and select him to. But every search, resets my selection. I'm looking for a possibility to save the selection and have A and B selected in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your views >> Exposed filter settings and check ***Remember the last selection*** checkbox

[image]

If you want to go further then try the [Views Saved Searches](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_savedsearches) module

> This module allows you to save your current configuration of exposed filters for later use. This can be especially useful for Views with a lot of exposed filters.
>
> Whenever a View is changed, all saved searches for that View are deleted, to prevent corruption. If the user has JavaScript enabled, the saving and deleting process happens through AHAH, and the new section is displayed below the exposed filters section. When JavaScript is disabled, the new section is displayed above the exposed filters section.

Comment: that would remember my selection in the search field, but not the items I already had selected. Maybe my question was a bit unclear but I want my selected items to be saved after new filtering. This is for batch-processing.